# How is it possible to add the MD5 hash in SharePoint Documents Library as a Column?

Tags: document-library

I'm trying to view the file's MD5 checksum next to the file. How is it possible?

[image]

Comment: already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951477/sharepoint-files-md5-hash

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the above reference to using event receivers is going to work for SharePoint Online (Office 365).
An alternative way is to create an Office Add-in or standalone upload page that allows users to upload one or more files. The code then calculates the MD5 hash for the file(s) and stores that in a SharePoint column.
This only works if the users only upload files through the above mentioned add-in or stand-alone page. Another thing to take into account is property promotion/demotion in SharePoint. When an Office file (or msg or tiff) is uploaded to SharePoint the file is changed. So the md5 hash needs to be calculated before it hits SharePoint.